# Changing value of $MYVIMRC

Tags: vimrc, plugin-fugitive

I store my `.vimrc` in my dotfiles repository located at `~/dotfiles/.vimrc`, which I want to manage with Git using [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). I have symlinks from my home directory to my dotfiles, i.e. `~/.vimrc -> ~/dotfiles/.vimrc`.

I two problems with this:

- I can't do something like `:edit $MYVIMRC`, change something and run `:Gcommit`, as [fugitive does not follow symbolic links](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/147). Via the symlink my `~/dotfiles/.vimrc` opens when running the edit command, but fugitive commands are not available.
- In my `.vimrc` I define a number of autocommands that do use `$MYVIMRC` - some of them do no longer work, because they also have their troubles with the symlink.

Both problems could be easily fixed if I could change the value of `$MYVIMRC`, but I can't figure out how to do that. **How can I change the value of `$MYVIMRC`?**

I understand that I can also just ignore `$MYVIMRC`, i.e. replace it in all autocommands and not use it to edit my `.vimrc`, but this seems not like a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` command in vimL allows you to assign a value to a variable. A variable may be a environment variable, or a register or an option.

```
 :let $MYVIMRC=value
```

This command sets the value to `$MYVIMRC`. You can put this in .vimrc.

Example:

```
 :let $MYVIMRC=C:\Users\acer\Desktop
```

Comment: Setting `let $MYVIMRC="/home/username/dotfiles/.vimrc"` in my `.vimrc` works as long as I don't open the symlinks. I am surprised that I could just set it like a normal variable, given its unusual variable name. Embarassing... Thanks :-)