# How to change where Vim will read .vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc

I'm re-learning Vim, and now I'm building my own `~/.vim/.vimrc` file. Yes, it is store under the `.vim/` folder, which is created by MacOSX after I updated to Big Sur. What I want is simply this

```
set belloff=all
```

when I put this line in `~/.vimrc` it works, while in `~/.vim/.vimrc` it's not. So my questions are:

1. What's the first file Vim read so it knows *Oh, so Mr. .vimrc your home is at `$HOME`(or `~`)*?
2. Which file should I change so that Vim will say *Ok, I should read Mr. .vimrc from `~/.vim/`*?

Comment: Have you tried to type `:h vimrc` and read what is written there?

Comment: @Matt: Thank you Matt! I didn't know there is a manual for this!

Comment: Reading Q&A [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation) is advised. Mastering Vim's help system is a must.

Comment: The file inside `~/.vim` is `vimrc` not `.vimrc`. You only need one dot: `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. For the first question

According to the help menu (see `:help $MYVIMRC`), vim will look for a user vimrc in specific places. It look first for `~/.vimrc` and then for `~/.vim/vimrc`. Vim stops searching after the first one found (that's why we need to remove `~/.vimrc`).

Vim will set automatically the `$MYVIMRC` environment variable to the location of the vimrc used.

#### 2. For the second question:

1. Put your vimrc content in `~/.vim/vimrc` (you must remove the `.`, so `vimrc` instead of `.vimrc`)
2. Remove `~/.vimrc`

Comment: Thank you Fabrice! Might I ask you that what is `$MYVIMRC`? Who will read it and what is it for?

Comment: You're welcome! I am not totally sure (I'm still learning myself), $MYVIMRC is one of the global variables Vim use to start. It contains the location of the actual vimrc (you can try `:echo $MYVIMRC` to see it or `:e $MYVIMRC` to open it) What I know is that it isn't a environnement variable of the system (no need trying to change it this way) but I think you can change it inside of vim (I have seen a post [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/changing-value-of-myvimrc))

Answer (score -1):

To solve the error "no .vimrc found. please set "vim.vimrc.path", you will need to create a configuration file for the Vim text editor called ".vimrc" and specify its location.
Here's how to do it:

1. Open a terminal window and navigate to your home directory:
   cd ~
2. Create a new file called ".vimrc" using the touch command:
   touch .vimrc
3. Open the ".vimrc" file in a text editor.
4. Add the following line to the ".vimrc" file, replacing "path/to/.vimrc" with the actual path to the ".vimrc" file:
   set vim.vimrc.path=path/to/.vimrc
5. Save the ".vimrc" file and exit the text editor.

Comment: There is no such setting as `vim.vimrc.path` I am flagging this answer